# How to trim last character when using ansible jinja loop

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My template like as blow

```
{% if hostvars[inventory_hostname].local_zk_server_id is defined  %}
zookeeperServers={% for host  in {{ groups[{{ target_hosts }}] %}}
"{{ hostvars[host].inventory_hostname }}:2181,"
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

output is`host1:2181,host2:2181,host3:2181,`

How to trim last comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible gotchas in your above template regarding variables access. Moreover, rather than trimming the last character in your string, the best solution is probably not to write it. Here is a better solution IMO in my below example fixing all the problems I'm referring to:

```
{% set zookeeperServers=[] %}
{% if hostvars[inventory_hostname].local_zk_server_id is defined  %}
{% for host in groups[target_hosts] %}
{% zookeeperServers.append(hostvars[host].inventory_hostname + ":2181") %}
{% endfor %}
zookeeperServers="{{ zookeeperServers | join(',') }}"
{% endif %}
```